# error: uncaughtException: provider.getConfiguredPinpointClient is not a function

Tags: aws-amplify

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Navigate to your amplify project directory.
2. Run `amplify notifications add`
3. Choose any name that you want to give your pinpoint project
4. Select email

**Problem:**

For aws-amplify, what causes the following error when running `amplify notifications add`?

> error: uncaughtException: provider.getConfiguredPinpointClient is not a function

**Logs:**

```
amplify notifications add
? Choose the push notification channel to enable. Email
An Amazon Pinpoint project will be created for notifications.
    ? Pinpoint project name kbdlist
    2019-01-22T01:10:48.293Z - error: uncaughtException: provider.getConfiguredPinpointClient is not a function date=Mon Jan 21 2019 18:10:48 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time), pid=35163, uid=501, gid=20, cwd=/Users/blakedietz/projects/kbdlist/kbdlist.com, execPath=/Users/blakedietz/.nvm/versions/node/v11.5.0/bin/node, version=v11.5.0, argv=[/Users/blakedietz/.nvm/versions/node/v11.5.0/bin/node, /Users/blakedietz/.nvm/versions/node/v11.5.0/bin/amplify, notifications, add], rss=144945152, heapTotal=115912704, heapUsed=73400600, external=587915, loadavg=[8.3427734375, 6.7333984375, 6.1748046875], uptime=803682, trace=[column=19, file=/Users/blakedietz/.nvm/versions/node/v11.5.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-notifications/lib/pinpoint-helper.js, function=getPinpointClient, line=228, method=null, native=false, column=32, file=/Users/blakedietz/.nvm/versions/node/v11.5.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-notifications/lib/pinpoint-helper.js, function=createApp, line=153, method=null, native=false, column=29, file=/Users/blakedietz/.nvm/versions/node/v11.5.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-notifications/lib/pinpoint-helper.js, function=createPinpointApp, line=69, method=null, native=false, column=7, file=internal/process/next_tick.js, function=process.internalTickCallback, line=77, method=internalTickCallback, native=false], stack=[TypeError: provider.getConfiguredPinpointClient is not a function,     at getPinpointClient (/Users/blakedietz/.nvm/versions/node/v11.5.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-notifications/lib/pinpoint-helper.js:228:19),     at createApp (/Users/blakedietz/.nvm/versions/node/v11.5.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-notifications/lib/pinpoint-helper.js:153:32),     at createPinpointApp (/Users/blakedietz/.nvm/versions/node/v11.5.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-notifications/lib/pinpoint-helper.js:69:29),     at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**

This is caused by having the incorrect path in your `project-config.json` for the `providers` key. This is likely to happen if you are using multiple computers or a node version manage such as `nvm` or `n`, as your path may change from the initial path added to the `providers` key in your `project-config.json`

**Solution:**

Change your `providers` path to the path that you have the `@aws-amplify/cli` package installed in.

So for example, before when the error was happening my providers value was

```
{
    ...
    "providers": {
        "awscloudformation": "/Users/blakedietz/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation"
    }
}
```

So I just updated the value from `v11.0.0` to `v11.5.0` as follows

```
{
    ...
    "providers": {
        "awscloudformation": "/Users/blakedietz/.nvm/versions/node/v11.5.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation"
    }
}
```